# Computer blocks the display of an iframe

Tags: iframe, port, firewall, content-security-policy

My company and I have developed a service consisting of two web applications:

- A collaborative platform (hereinafter called Platform) accessible through an address similar to online.contoso.com, written in ASP.NET and React and running on a Windows Server 2016 server. This platform authenticates and authorizes users and allows them to perform various operations;
- A web application (hereinafter called App) accessible through an address similar to online.contoso.com:44312, written in Django and jQuery and running on the same previous server;

Platform exposes App through the following iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://online.contoso.com:44312?lng=en" id="PlanningFrameId" width="100%" height="645px" style="display: block; border: 0px;"></iframe>
```

App uses the following Content-Security-Policy:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *.contoso.com online.contoso.com
```

Some of our customers declare that they are unable to load App. For example, today two of our customers declare that one is able to see App and the other is not. The two users use the same internet connection but two different computers (both Macs). The customer who does not see App has performed a check with both Safari and Google Chrome. Is there any reason why a computer can block certain iframes (both Mac and Windows)?

We have performed tests on both a Platform and on the App and the applications work correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange thing is not that on some PCs the application does not work, but that on some it does.

The `*.contoso.com` host-source allows `https://*.contoso.com:443` on https: pages and allows `http://*.contoso.com:80`  on http: pages (only [standard ports](http://csplite.com/csp/test284/) are allowed by default).

Therefore you have to add `https://online.contoso.com:44312` source into policy:
`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *.contoso.com https://*.contoso.com:44312`

Note: `online.contoso.com` is excessive because it's covered by `*.contoso.com`.